# regex edit in skype?

Tags: linux, skype, regex

Ok, I am not a big skype user, but I was chatting with my sister, made a typo and habitually typed

```
tpyo
s/tpyo/typo/
```

to my surprise it actually changed the history. I am using the linux skype client 2.1.0.47-r1 and my sister is using 4.something on windows.

When she tried to do the same thing, it didn't work. Does anyone know if this is specific to the linux version?

Coolest easter egg/feature I have ever stumbled upon.

Comment: Also, note that *you* might see the changes, but (some of) the other person(s) in the chat might not. (I've never managed to figure out *when* it works, nor if I could somehow tell *if* it worked. Very confusing if you're trying a make a joke that just doesn't even make it to the Skype client on the other side...)

Comment: wow, cool! too bad it doesn't work on windows :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regexp feature does not work on Windows. It works on the Linux and Mac version though. It's a pretty neat feature, you can also hold Control-click (Mac) and select **Edit** from the context menu on a message to edit it.

Comment: (Using Edit suffers the same issue I commented on in the question: *you* might see the changes, but other(s) might not...)

Comment: Yeah they both do the same thing.

Comment: Right click works on linux too. One can even remove a message.