# What is the full extent of s/old/new and /find in Skype commands

Tags: skype

Skype has the following in their [help section](https://support.skype.com/en-us/faq/FA10042/What-are-chat-commands-and-roles)

```
/find [text]
```

Finds specific text in a chat. For example, /find Lucien will return the first instance of the word "Lucien" in the chat.

I have not able to find one for s/ but it works.

so far I was able to try

```
s/old/new/
s/old and new/new and new/
```

Can anyone describe what are the features that are available to me in the s/ and /find commands ? For example: Can I replace in multiple lines ?

Comment: Related but not a dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/95155/regex-edit-in-skype

Comment: Beware that the recipient might not see the changes. Don't know why, but I've seen my old text on the screens of my colleagues long after I edited a word. And no feedback whatsoever.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `s/` command is a carryover from the old UNIX command `sed`. Contrary to what a lot of people on the Internet seem to think — based on my recent Googling — it isn't related to regular expressions. There's a great reference for `sed` [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

However, Skype seems to only support the basic syntax, and only for the most recent message. If another message has been sent or received, you're out of luck. This easter egg only works on non-Windows versions, and assumes that the `g` or `global` flag is set. There doesn't seem to be any official documentation about this from Skype itself.

Comment: Not sure if you're saying otherwise, but surely `sed` allows for regular expressions in its substitute command.

Comment: @Arjan, sorry, I was trying to say that a lot of blog posts about this feature seem to think that `s/old/new` is itself a regular expression. FWIW though, it seems that this "Skype sed" doesn't support regexps, just exact text matches.

Comment: FYI, `ed` had `s///` in 1971, two years before `sed`, and it too did regexps.

Comment: Hmmm, where does the term regex stop? I'd say a regular expression is more than just its pattern. In Perl, I'd call the whole substitute operation a regex, like in `$a =~ s/foo/bar/g;`. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @grawity, yeah, I did come across that in my travels, but I think it's much more associated with `sed`, so I went with that.

Comment: Very, very sadly seems to have been removed with the most recent update (OSX)